# OpenJPA, memory overhead for huge number of insertions

Tags: jpa, garbage-collection, openjpa

Basically I am creating a sort of graph on a huge dataset. I keep a bunch of nodes in memory and then I iteratively load another bunch of those to create the edges that connect them with the previous one, then I change the ones that I keep in memory and so on.

A java-like pseudocode could be something like this:

```
while(externalIterator.hasNext()) {
  Set<Node> bunch1 = externalIterator.next();
  em.getTransaction().begin();
  internalIterator = nodeBunchList.iterator();
  while(internalIterator.hasNext()) {
    Set<Node> bunch2 = internalIterator.next();
    computesEdges(bunch1, bunch2);
  }
  em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

The problems are:

1. computesEdges does a massive amount of insertions that shouldn't be cached or keeped in memory by the EntityManager. For now, once in a while, I do em.clear(). It does work but it spends an unbeliveable amount of time doing Garbage Collection.
2. The nodes from the second iterator shouldn't be kept in memory too, since they are used just once.

I was wondering if there is a way to say to the entity manager not to keep in memory all those things, but to get rid of them as soon as I don't use it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there is a way to say to the entity manager not to
>   keep in memory all those things, but to get rid of them as soon as I
>   don't use it anymore.

Calling EntityManager.clear() tells JPA that it is safe to clear the persistence context. If you are making any changes to the database, you'll always want to call EntityManager.flush() so that your changes are flushed out to the db.

To increase the speed of the EntityManager.clear() call, try to enable the [LiteAutoDetach](http://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/trunk/docbook/manual.html#ref_guide_detach_state) feature of OpenJPA.

```
<property name="openjpa.DetachState" value="loaded(LiteAutoDetach=true)"/>
```